# Женственная женщина

Tags: тавтология

Можно ли сказать о женщине, что она женственная? Например, — *"Юля очень женственная".* Нет уверенности в том, что так можно говорить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из словаря: ЖЕНСТВЕННЫЙ,  **Обладающий признаками, качествами, присущими женщине;** **мягкий, нежный, изящный**. Ж-ая натура.  Обаятельна и на редкость женственна.  Она выглядит особенно ж. в вечернем платье. Женственность и  грация присущи ей от природы.

Но мужчины тоже могут быть женственными: С третьего портрета смотрел на меня какой-то уж очень красивый, круглолицый, даже немного женственный молодой человек в светлых одеждах и белой высокой чалме.

Comment: Спасибо, Sibylla!

Answer (score 2):

"Юля очень женственная"... Напрягать может ОЧЕНЬ, поскольку и так уж женщина женственна, и сверх того — будет неприкрытой лестью или формой речи, способной вызвать обратный эффект. Лучше всё-таки уточнять в какой части проявляется эта самая женственность. По крайней мере мужчине следует быть готовым разъяснить смысл сказанного. Дамы без этого не могут.

Comment: Но сказать о женщине, что она НЕ женственная, вполне можно. В наше непростое время это вполне распространённое явление.

Comment: «Сказать О женщине, что она не женственная, вполне можно», но осторожно, лучше — вообще, когда беседуешь под рюмочку с умным человеком в зеркале. Другие продадут.

Comment: :) Россия не так заражена феминизмом как прогнивший Запад

Comment: Насчёт "в какой части проявляется женственность" - мне кажется что применительно к женщине, это эвфемизм понятия "сексуальность". То, что по-американски бездуховно называeтся sexy. Так что, если дама будет настаивать, можно и уточнить :)

Answer (score 1):

Я уже вижу в комментариях упоминания феминизма etc., но упомянуть об условном "сексизме" будет не лишним) в самом деле, так уж повелось в мировой культуре и общественном сознании, что "мужчины с Марса, женщины с Венеры" и пр., и на момент возникновения прилагательного "женственный" различия эти были не так нивелированы. В итоге женщина сейчас может быть женственной, может быть мужеподобной или вообще андрогинной. Но если существо "прекрасного пола" (ну вот опять!) выглядит так, как предписывает "классика", его несомненно назовут женственным.

Comment: А если к теме ближе? Называть — это не всегда «произнести», не всегда «сказать, говорить».

Comment: А если ближе - называют. "Женственная женщина" стараются не употреблять по понятным причинам, а в остальном - употребляется. Звучит не слишком хорошо, но по смыслу вполне уместно бывает.